# UIWebView search

Tags: objective-c, ios, search, uikit, uiwebview

What is the best way to search for a string of text in a `UIWebView`?

Comment: Changed tags as this is not strictly related to the iPhone, but it is to iOS, UIKit and Objective-C.

Comment: I put together a sample project in case anyone else is asking the same question. The project is a super simple app that loads an HTML file and can search and highlight any keyword. You can download the sample project here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12280770/TheSearcher.zip

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/

Comment: I want to do same in swift but my JS method is no calling in swift

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that the best to proceed is to:

1. Create a javascript function that will find your text
2. Use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` [(see here)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) method to get the javascript code
3. Call the same method to look for the `javascript` function (put this code in a function that will take the `aString` argument):

   NSString *findThisStringFnc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"findThisString('%@')",aString];
   [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:findThisStringFnc ];
4. Put all this code in a function (`findAString` for example) then call it from the `UIWebView` instance:
   [aWebView findAString:@"foobar"];