# How to highlight all occurrences of a string in a UIWebView every time the web view finishes loading?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

So I basically have a `UIWebView` on the screen. There are two `UIBarButtonItem`s that the user can tap to load HTML on the web view. One button for loading the next HTML and one for loading the previous one. (I have an array of HTMLs to display)

So I used this code to load the HTML every time the user taps on one of the buttons:

```
// resultView is a UIWebView
resultView.loadHTMLString(
    entries[nowDisplayingIndex].htmlDescription, baseURL: nil)
```

Every time a piece of HTML has been displayed, I use Javascript to highlight all occurrences of some string. I decided to load the Javascript functions into the web view when `viewDidLoad`. So I created a method that is called in `viewDidLoad`:

```
extension UIWebView {
    func initializeHighlighting() {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("highlight", ofType: "js")
        let jsCode = try! String(contentsOfFile: path!)
        self.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsCode)!
    }
}
```

And the js file is as follows:

```
function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) {

    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node
            while (true) {
                //if (counter < 1) {
                var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
                var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

                if (idx < 0) break;             // not found, abort

                //(value.split);

                //we create a SPAN element for every parts of matched keywords
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx,keyword.length));
                span.appendChild(text);

                span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");
                span.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
                span.style.color="black";

                text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
                element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
                var next = element.nextSibling;
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
                element = text;
                window.scrollTo(0,span.offsetTop);

            }
        } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
            if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// the main entry point to start the search
function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(keyword) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("searchtext");
        uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase());
}

// helper function, recursively removes the highlights in elements and their childs
function uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 1) {
            if (element.getAttribute("class") == "uiWebviewHighlight") {
                var text = element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text,element);
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                return true;
            } else {
                var normalize = false;
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    if (uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element.childNodes[i])) {
                        normalize = true;
                    }
                }
                if (normalize) {
                    element.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// the main entry point to remove the highlights
function uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights() {
    uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(document.body);
}
```

I basically copied this from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420496/highlight-text-in-uiwebview) and did a few changes to it.

In the `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate method, I called this function:

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(
    "uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('\(searchText)')")
```

My logic was that every time the user taps a button, a new HTML is loaded. And `webViewDidFinishLoad` will be called. Then, text will be highlighted when the Javascript function is called.

I ran my app, and I can see that some texts are highlighted in the web view. However, when I tap on the button and the next HTML is displayed, the highlight is gone! Then I tapped on the button to load the previous HTML but I still can't see the highlights.

I don't understand why this happens so I started trying random things.

I added a button that calls the Javascript function but the result stays the same. I also tried returning an HTML with the Javascript functions in the `htmlDescription` property, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are injecting the highlight.js only when viewDidLoad is called, which isn't sufficient, you need to inject the highlight js every time the webview is loaded. webViewDidFinishLoad

Comment: I tried to inject the highlight.js both before and after it started loading the HTML but the result is still the same. @GuyS

Comment: Do it with js and [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).